# How does Async.AwaitTask work in f#?

Tags: f#

I understand that the main difference between f# and c# async model is that in f#, the async execution does not begin unless you call something like Async.RunSynchronously. In c#, when a method returns a task, execution is usually (not always) immediately started in a background thread.

Async.AwaitTask documentation says "Returns an asynchronous computation that waits for the given task to complete and returns its result."

Does that mean, when you call a c# method that returns a task, execution already started in the background? If so, what is the point of wrapping it inside an Async type anymore?

Comment: "In c#, when a method returns a task, execution already started in a background thread." - No, not necessarily. It depends on how the task was created as to whether or not it starts automatically.

Comment: @Enigmativity you are right. I made the update. I'm asking this question in the context when a c# method does Task.Run(some action here).

Comment: What do you mean by "wrapping it inside an Async type"?

Comment: Maybe i'm not using the right terminology here. Let's say getCustomerAsync returns Task<Customer>. If I call, Async.AwaitTask, it returns Async<Customer>. I don't understand why it returns Async<Customer> if the task already begun in the background.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The point of wrapping a Task inside an Async is to more easily compose it with other asyncs, or to use it with `let!` from inside an `async { ... }` block. And in the latter case, the wrapped Task won't be started until its enclosing `async { ... }` block is started.

For example, let's look at the following function:

```
let printTask str =
  async {
    printfn "%s" str
  } |> Async.StartAsTask
```

This doesn't do much; its only reason for existence is so that you can tell when it has started running, because it will print a message to the screen. If you call it from F# Interactive:

```
printTask "Hello"
```

You'll see the following output:

```
Hello
val it : Threading.Tasks.Task<unit> =
  System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit]
    {AsyncState = null;
     CreationOptions = None;
     Exception = null;
     Id = 4;
     IsCanceled = false;
     IsCompleted = true;
     IsCompletedSuccessfully = true;
     IsFaulted = false;
     Status = RanToCompletion;}
```

So it printed "Hello" and then returned the completed Task. This proves that the Task was started immediately.

But now look at the following code:

```
open System.Net
open System
open System.IO

let printTask str =
  async {
    printfn "%s" str
  } |> Async.StartAsTask

let fetchUrlAsync url =
  async {
    let req = WebRequest.Create(Uri(url))
    do! printTask ("started downloading " + url) |> Async.AwaitTask
    use! resp = req.GetResponseAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
    use stream = resp.GetResponseStream()
    use reader = new IO.StreamReader(stream)
    let html = reader.ReadToEnd()
    do! printTask ("finished downloading " + url) |> Async.AwaitTask
  }
```

(This is [Scott Wlaschin's "Async Web Downloader" example](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/concurrency-async-and-parallel/#example-an-async-web-downloader), adapted to use Tasks instead of Asyncs internally).

Here, the `async { ... }` block contains three Tasks, all of which are wrapped in `Async.AwaitTask`. (Note that if you removed `|> Async.AwaitTask` from any of these lines, you'd get a type error). For each Task, *once its line of code executes*, it will start right away. But that's an important point, because the overall `async { ... }` computation is *not* started right away. So I can do:

```
let a = fetchUrlAsync "http://www.google.com"
```

And the only thing printed in F# Interactive is `val a : Async<unit>`. I can wait as long as I want to, and nothing else is printed. Only once I actually *start* `a` will it start running:

```
a |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

This prints `started downloading http://www.google.com` immediately, then after a short pause it prints `finished downloading http://www.google.com`.

So that's the purpose of `Async.AwaitTask`: to allow `async { ... }` blocks to more easily interoperate with C# code that returns Tasks. And if the Async.AwaitTask call is inside an `async { ... }` block, then the Task won't actually start until the enclosing `Async` is started, so you still get all the advantages of "cold-start" Asyncs.