# How to write Func<Task> in F#

Tags: f#

I have some C# code from https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/api/class-filechooser

```
var fileChooser = await page.RunAndWaitForFileChooserAsync(async () =>
{
    await page.ClickAsync("upload");
});
await fileChooser.SetFilesAsync("temp.txt");
```

and I am trying to convert to F# but a bit lost

```
let! filechooser = page.RunAndWaitForFileChooserAsync(page.ClickAsync("//label[contains(text(),'Upload')]")) |> Async.AwaitTask
do! filechooser.SetFilesAsync("c:\\csv\\"+filename) |> Async.AwaitTask
```

I get the error: 'Task' is not compatible with 'Func<Task>'

The "offending" code is

```
page.ClickAsync("//label[contains(text(),'Upload')]")
```

Update: if I change it to the code below

```
let! filechooser = page.RunAndWaitForFileChooserAsync( fun () -> page.ClickAsync("//label[contains(text(),'Upload')]") )  |> Async.AwaitTask
```

.. it will run - but it doesn't actually execute the inner code: ( i.e. page.ClickAsync )

Update:

If I run:
do! page.ClickAsync("//label[contains(text(),'Upload')]") |> Async.AwaitTask

That will click on the correct button and open the file chooser.  but if I put it inside the correct context , it doesn't open at all

```
let! filechooser = page.RunAndWaitForFileChooserAsync( fun () -> task { do! page.ClickAsync("//label[contains(text(),'Upload')]") |> Async.AwaitTask } )  |> Async.AwaitTask
```

Comment: does `fun () -> page.ClickAsync("someselector")` work?

Comment: unfortunately, no.  It doesn't break the code - but it doesn't actually execute the page.alickAsync.

Comment: `fun () -> task { do! page.ClickAsync("someselector") }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Async.AwaitTask work in f#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51182313/how-does-async-awaittask-work-in-f)

Answer (score 1):

If you have F# 6 and the [`task` computation expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/task-expressions) then you shouldn't need to use `Async.AwaitTask` at all.

Untested but the direct translation of the sample seems to be:

```ml
let doFileChooser (page:IPage) =
    let t = 
        task {
            let! filechooser = page.RunAndWaitForFileChooserAsync(fun () ->
                task {
                    do! page.ClickAsync("upload")
                })

            do! filechooser.SetFilesAsync("temp.txt")
        }
    t.Wait()
```